# Is there any way to add synchronous delay to d3 attr updates in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to create an Aho-Corasick Visualizer. The aho-corasick algorithm is a string search algorithm that searches for patterns/substrings within a mainstring. It does so by constructing a aho-corasick automaton (essentially a trie structure) and traversing the nodes of said automaton.

I am using React. I have visualized the node trie using d3 and have created a button that runs a visualize function when it is pressed. The function loops through the mainstring and goes through the nodes on the d3 node tree to search.

```
function visualize(e) {
    //loop through mainstring chars
    for (let i = 0; i < mainstring.length + 1; i++) {
        //set current node to a diffrent color
        svg.select('#kc' + currNode.toString()).style('fill','red');

        //the function picks and traverses the nodes here in this loop
        //finds the next node to proceed to and continues
    }
}
```

Currently the program works but it is impossible to see the order in which the search traverses the nodes because the loop is near instantaneuous. You can see the instantaneous color changes here: https://kenneth-ye.github.io/AhoCorasick-Algorithm-Visualizer/  (just press search and visualize).

You can see the full visualize function here at line 194: https://github.com/Kenneth-Ye/AhoCorasick-Algorithm-Visualizer/blob/master/src/d3visualization.js

I would like to add a delay in between each repition of the loop so that the order is visible like in this example: https://brunorb.github.io/ahocorasick/visualization.html

I have tried implementing a delay using setTimeout but what it does is it waits for the culmulative delay (i.e if there are 5 letters in the mainstring and program should delay 2000ms for each letter, program waits for 10s) and the highlights all the nodes that are traversed.

I have also used Promise and await but the program throuw and await only allowed in async function error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async promise` that wraps your setTimeout should work:

```
const delay = 2000 * mainstring.length;
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
```

So in your code it looks like:

```
function visualize(e) {
    //loop through mainstring chars
    const delay = 2000 * mainstring.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < mainstring.length + 1; i++) {
        //set current node to a diffrent color
        svg.select('#kc' + currNode.toString()).style('fill','red');
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay)); // <--delay
        //the function picks and traverses the nodes here in this loop
        //finds the next node to proceed to and continues
    }
}
```